# React Firebase, realtime cursor position watcher can't handle updates

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I am writing a module that lets you track your mouse coordinates on another person his screen. I am writing the X and Y coordinates to firebase. The `onMouseMove write event goes really smooth and Firebase updates perfectly fine without lag. However my read event has some trouble keeping up:

```
        .child('activity')
        .on('value', snapshot => {
          if (snapshot.val()) {
            friendDashboardActivityData[userKey] = snapshot.val();
            if (document.getElementById('cursor' + userKey)) {
              /** Place the element based on the coordinates */
              let d = document.getElementById('cursor' + userKey);
              d.style.left = snapshot.val()['cursor'].x + 'px';
              d.style.top = snapshot.val()['cursor'].y + 'px';
```

The mouse that appears on screen is really laggy because it can't handle the many changes per second in firebase. Is there a socket like connector in firebase (or perhaps we made a mistake somewhere) that we can use, so i seems that the cursor is moving smoothly.

Comment: I think is because you are listening to a parent node instead of only what you need. Firebase real time is a socket under the hood, so nothing to do there. Try to listen to node specific of the cursos something like `child("activity/userKey/cursor")`